# Intermittent Wireless Issue, Linux Mint, New Laptop, Other Devices Connect

Tags: wireless-networking, laptop, linux-mint

After scouring the internet, no set of answers can solve the problem (software or hardware) as to why my connection appears then dissapears inconsistently.

A simple case would be...

- Connect to a wired connection.
- Disconnect to wireless connection (move away from router if near).
- The connection can hold it's own but either after much network use / sat pinging away.
- It disconnects, suddenly cannot find the router.
- Messages include "No buffer space available"  then "Destination Host Unreachable"
- All other devices (around 9 others) do not have this problem.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please try to be more precise about what the problem is. Your title says you're having a wireless issue but your bulletted list says that the problem occurs when you have a wired connection and have already disconnected from wireless.

Comment: Apologies. I use the wired connection to gain internet access before disconnecting - once disconnected the wireless access will last at the most 5 minutes before dropping (this can be accelerated by moving away or frequently using the internet)

Answer (score 1):

So I have finally solved the problem! The issue eventually came down to the Linux kernel version I had installed. [This handy little guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119080/how-to-update-kernel-to-the-latest-mainline-version-without-any-distro-upgrade) pointed me in the right direction.

Linux Mint on installation is set at V13.*

What you really need is the latest V17.*.

As a side note, I should mention that issues still appear if the computer goes to sleep as it cannot reconnect (requires a full shutdown) - this, would be a different issue however…